# HTML Inside of Link

Tags: html, email, hyperlink

I'm sending out an HTML email. I'd like the recipient to be able to click the link from their email inbox and then have the HTML nested inside the link to be opened and rendered in their browser.

```
EMAIL:
<html>
   <body>
      <a href= **<html><body> You're now viewing this in browser </body></html>**>  Click here to render HTML in browser. </a>
   </body>
</html>
```

This is for a work email to colleagues, hence the reason I don't have a webpage to direct them to. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It *might* be possible to do something like this with a `data:` url, in the format:

```
data:text/html,%3Ch1%3EHello%2C%20World!%3C%2Fh1%3E
```

Although I don't know if email clients will allow `data:` urls in links. My guess would be 'no' because it's probably a security problem.

Since you're looking to render something in a browser after clicking the link in the email, have you considered making a minimal website on a `http://` url?